# Can you explain the difference between jdbcTemplate methods preparedStatementCallBack and preparedStatementSetter to avoid sql Injection?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, prepared-statement, sql-injection, jdbctemplate

I want to avoid sql injection in my application.There are two jdbcTemplate method like

```
public <T> T execute(String sql,PreparedStatementCallback<T> action)throws DataAccessException
```

OR

```
public <T> T query(String sql,@Nullable,PreparedStatementSetter pss,ResultSetExtractor<T> rse)
throws DataAccessException
```

OR

Any Other method you can suggest to avoid sql injection.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: SQL Injections is about user misbehavior, could you specify whats are the entry points from the user to your SQL statement? I ask this because you could clear these user inputs, avoiding SQL Injection, despite the JDBC Template Method used.

Comment: LIke entering id(varchar) of particular user and submitting . And in the backend with the help of that id data is being retrieved and showed to the user. Apart from this do you know difference between these two methods. I am just curious to know the difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR

**Execute** method allows you to execute any arbitrary data access operation within one single statement.

**Query** method lets you send a query using a prepared statement.

For these and all other methods from the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html) there are some methods that can deal with the same circumstances. It's up to the developer to choose those that are most convenient for their job.

As a suggestion, I would recommend using some patterns like the query method for retrieving data, and the [update](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#update-java.lang.String-) method to insert, update or delete data.